# C# Error with Positions

Tags: c#

http://prntscr.com/2385hq
is the error I get in my .exe file when I open it.

Here's the code it's saying is wrong:

```
else
{
   if (NewUserGrid[Actor.Position.X, Actor.Position.Y] == null)
   {
   NewUserGrid[Actor.Position.X, Actor.Position.Y] = new List<RoomActor>();
   }
   NewUserGrid[Actor.Position.X, Actor.Position.Y].Add(Actor);
}
```

the line that's saying is wrong is

```
if (NewUserGrid[Actor.Position.X, Actor.Position.Y] == null)
```

Comment: When you say it's wrong what do you mean? Is there an error message?

Comment: I think you will need to post more of your code...

Comment: No, it's failing in a call to `File.ReadAllText`...

Comment: and the full error message. what tool are you using? have you tried debugging?

Comment: The file is currently inaccessible because it's blocked by another process

Comment: kill the other process - or use sysinternals process explorer (or similar) to close the handle by hand

Comment: If it's being used by another process then how do I change that? :/ I'm new, sorry.

Comment: Would having C# 2010 Express open change it? I wouldn't see why.

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih Not exactly by another process. May be the same process also can do that

Comment: I don't get this, can someone help? It keeps crashing my program. I tried the unlock thing from one of the answers but it said failed to unlock.

Answer (score 0):

the file is used by another process. you can check what it is using [iobit unlocker](http://www.iobit.com/iobit-unlocker.php) or any other similar tool. you might have forgotten to close a previous test-run, and the program preventing the reading is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace says, the resource (file) you are trying to access is been used by another process. More likely, this happens when you fail to release file properly or have parallel running applications that uses the same file.

Following pattern properly release file after it's use. This deterministic approach can be achieved using c#'s `using` statement.

```
using(open your file here)
{
    //the using statement will handle releasing the resource.
}
```

[More on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx)

Comment: catch (Exception e)
            {
                string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\log.txt");
                Output.WriteLine("Error in Pathfinder: " + e.Message + "\n\n" + e.StackTrace);
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\log.txt");
                file.WriteLine(text + "Error in Pathfinder: " + e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace + "\n\n" + e.StackTrace,
                    OutputLevel.Notification + "\n\n");
            }

I don't see what's wrong. that's where the error is for open

Comment: @user2976681, it's very difficult to workout your case since you are not showing enough code to diagnose. I have enclosed a link, which has few sample on how to achieve writing to a file.